# Kubeflow could not be enabled

Tags: juju

I am trying to install kubeflow with microk8s on ubuntu-20, but there is an error during deployment:

I am running the following command:

```
microk8s.enable kubeflow
```

With the following output:

```
Enabling dns...
Enabling storage...
Enabling dashboard...
Enabling ingress...
Enabling metallb:10.64.140.43-10.64.140.49...
Waiting for DNS and storage plugins to finish setting up
Deploying Kubeflow...
Kubeflow could not be enabled:
ERROR cannot deploy bundle: cannot add charm "cs:~kubeflow-charmers/ambassador-89": cannot retrieve charm "cs:~kubeflow-charmers/ambassador-89": cannot get archive:
Get https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/~kubeflow-charmers/ambassador-89/archive?channel=stable: dial tcp: lookup api.jujucharms.com on 10.152.183.10:53: server misbehaving
Command '('microk8s-juju.wrapper', 'deploy', 'cs:kubeflow-195', '--channel', 'stable', '--overlay', '/tmp/tmpsh6tvw23')' returned non-zero exit status 1
Failed to enable kubeflow
```

How do I fix this?